# Paypal IPN for other peoples accounts, with a deduction fee

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-ipn

They do the exact method I'm looking to recreate on http://sellfy.com/
What I'm looking to do is be able to setup autopayment systems for people. I'm going to use the dynamic notification URL( notify_url ) in the HTML form code. But what I don't understand is how once a persons buys a product, the sellers account sends 5% of the transaction back to sellfy?

Comment: I would presume payment goes to sellfy, who forwards 95% of it to the seller

Comment: No it doesn't, that's what I find weird. This is the account im using to sell stuff on sellfy http://puu.sh/6nt9i.png

Comment: As described, that is a chained payment, where the primary receiver gets the full amount and the rest is automatically forwarded to a secondary receiver.

Comment: If you're working with PHP you may want to check out my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) as it would make this very simple for you to setup.

Answer (score 1):

They probably don't send 5% back. Sellify is probably using [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), which has something called Chained Payments as part of it. It allows you to make a payment to one person, but take a cut yourself.